# file_get_contents url returns empty string, while fsockopen works fine?

Tags: php, fopen, file-get-contents, php-5.3

I am having a strange behaviour on a ubuntu server (nginx php5-fpm stack) following code explains the problem:

```
<?php
// WORKS:
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}

// DOES NOT WORK! Return empty string (no error like NULL or False whatsoever).
echo file_get_contents("http://www.example.com");

// allow_ftp_open is On
echo var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen')); // returns '1'
?>
```

Following code using fopen:

```
<?php
// get contents of a file into a string
$filename = "http://www.example.com";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
echo $contents;
?>
```

Generates this:

```
Warning: filesize(): stat failed for http://www.example.com in test.php on line 5

Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 in test.php on line 5
```

If I use a fixed size in fread, the result is an empty string just like with file_get_contents.

How can it be that sockets work fine, but fopen does not? What am I missing?

Comment: What is allow_url_fopen set to?

Comment: It's set to On. var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) returns "1"

Answer (score 0):

When reading from anything that is not a regular local file, reading will stop after a packet is available. Try something like this

```
if ($fp = fopen('http://www.example.com/', 'r')) {
   $contents = '';
   while ($line = fread($fp, 1024)) {
      $contents.= $line;
   }
}
```

Comment: just did, stream_get_contents returns an empty string "". :(

Comment: fopen should support http protocol to open urls (http://php.net/manual/de/function.fopen.php). I would use sockets, but I cannot. My main concern is the SoapClient, which seems to be using either fopen or file_get_contents. When I try to create a new SoapClient($url), I always get the error:

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://.....' : Start tag expected, '<' not found.... 

Probably because the response is an empty string (as with fopen and file_get_contents)

Comment: Yes, you are right. can you try with updated code to read data in loop because it may possible that reading get stop after a packet or so.

Comment: the code within if, block gets executed (hence $fp is not null), however the while-block is not executed not even once..